# Including header files in multiple source files in C

Tags: c

Consider the following example:
Header.h:

```
typedef struct
{
    int value;
}My_Struct;

void edit(int num);
int get();
```

Header.c

```
My_Struct data={0};

void edit(int num)
{
      data.value = num;
}
int get()
{
     Return data.value;
}
```

If two files file1.c and file2.c both include header.h and file1.c calls the edit function to change value to 99, will a get function called from file2.c return 99 or the initialised 0?

Im hoping it will return 0 and each file has its own copy of My_Struct.

Comment: But anyways, you are hoping for the wrong thing here.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll be disappointed of the result. BTW: what about test it yourself? And get function should `return data.value`

Comment: I don't have a computer handy it was just a thought while on the bus

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks: "what does this code do". Answer: test yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming file1.c and file2.c are linked into a single executable along with header.c, they will be referencing the same variable.  So if you call `edit` with a value of 99 from a function in file1.c, a subsequent call to `get` from a function in file2.c will return 99.

The only way you could get different results is if you were to pass an instance of `My_Struct` to these functions, so each calling function could use a different instance.

If on the other hand file1.c and file2.c are each linked into separate executables, then each one (each running instance, actually) will have its own copy of `data`.

Comment: If File1.c and file2.c will be linked into separate executables then it would be ok?

Comment: @Koi If they're in separate executables then yes they will be separate.

Comment: Actually what if the header.h and header.c files are used to generate a library.... And other applications use that library.......will the executables have their own copy of data?

Comment: @Koi Yes, each executable will have its own copy.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't the `Header.h` file; the issue is in the `Header.c` file:

```
My_Struct data={0};

void edit(int num)
{
      data.value = num;
}
int get()
{
     Return data.value;
}
```

You've created a *single* instance of the `data` variable and made it global (meaning it can be accessed by name from another translation unit).  Assuming you build `Header.c`, `file1.c` and `file2.c` into a single executable:

```
gcc -o test0 file1.c file2.c Header.c
```

then only a single instance of `data` exists over the entire program, so any changes made to it by the code in `file1.c` will be picked up by the code in `file2.c` and vice-versa.

If you want to *guarantee* that `file1.c` and `file2.c` are dealing with separate instances of `data` *regardless* of whether they're linked into the same executable or not, then the right way to go about this is to change the `get` and `edit` functions so that they take a `MyStruct` as a parameter:

```
// Header.h
typedef struct { int value; } MyStruct;

void edit( int num, MyStruct *data);  
int get( MyStruct data);  

// Header.c
void edit( int num, MyStruct *data)
{
  data->value = num;
}

int get( MyStruct data)
{
  return data.value;
}
```

And then create separate instances of `data` within `file1.c` and `file2.c`:

```
// file1.c
#include "Header.h"

static MyStruct data = {0}; // static instance, not visible outside of file1.c,
                            // exists over lifetime of program

void foo( void )
{
  ...
  edit( 99, &data );
  ...
}

void bar( void )
{
  ...
  printf( "data contains %d\n", get( data ) );
  ...
}

// file2.c
#include "Header.h"

static MyStruct data = {0}; // Another static instance, not visible outside of file2.c
                            // exists over lifetime of program

void bletch( void )
{
  ...
  edit( 42, &data );
  ...
}

void blurga( void )
{
  ...
  printf( "data contains %d\n", get( data ) );
  ...
}
```

If the linker sees the same file-scope object name declaration in multiple translation units (files), it will try to map those multiple declarations to a single object instance.  If we declared `data` *without* the `static` keyword in `file1.c` and `file2.c`, then the linker would have created only a single instance of `data`, and we'd be back where we started<sup>1</sup>.

The `static` keyword tells the compiler to not export the object name to the linker; it effectively makes that instance of `data` "private" to the source file.  So, when `file1.c` and `file2.c` are linked into the same executable, they'll each have their own "private" instance of `data`, so changes made to `data` by code in `file1.c` won't be visible to the code in `file2.c`, and vice versa.

Note that wherever possible, you *don't* want to create objects at file scope.  As a rule, functions should communicate using parameters and return values; they should not share state through global values unless it's *absolutely* necessary.

---

1. Actually, I'm not sure what happens when we have multiple *defining* declarations like we do in this case (the presence of the initializer makes it a defining declaration).  I want to say the linker will complain, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot keep different values for each from same reference. To do that you can define an array of the struct like :

```
int n = 2;
My_Struct structsOfMine[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have the following two lines in both file1.c and file2.c, you'll get 99.

♯include "Header.h"

extern My_Struct data;

Answer (score 0):

If `file1.c` and `file2.c` only include the header, then when you compile them to object files and link them to make a program, it will fail due to the unresolved symbols `get` and `edit`.

If you link both object object files together with the translation of `Header.c` into one program, then they share one single instance of the object called `data` which is provided by a single external definition in the entire program: the definition `My_Struct data={0};`.  The `Header.h` file only declares the type `My_Struct`.

You can link `file1.c` with `Header.c` into one program, and then link `file1.c` and `Header.c` into another program. Then those two units are in separate programs and do not share the same `data`.

If you want the effect in one program, you can change `Header.h` like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int value;
}My_Struct;

static My_Struct data={0};

static void edit(int num)
{
      data.value = num;
}

static int get()
{
     Return data.value;
}
```

Now every translation unit which includes this header gets its own external definition of `data` and the two functions, which refer to that same `data`. These definitions of `data`, `edit` and `get` have *internal linkage* thanks to the `static` storage class specifier, making them invisible from other translation units.